# array and object handling in javascript for getting highchart json data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, highcharts

I have array structure of employee information in JavaScript

```
var emplyeeinfo=[{
    empNo: 12302,
    empId: '30984',
    empJobCategory: 'Designer',
  },
  {
    empNo: 14785,
    empId: '33420',
    empJobCategory: 'Associate Manager',
  },
  {
    empNo: 13710,
    empId: '32603',
    empJobCategory: 'Designer',
  },
  {
    empNo: 13783,
    empId: '32675',
    empJobCategory: 'Designer',
  },
  {
    empNo: 15069,
    empId: '33619',
    empJobCategory: 'Designer',
  },
  {
    empNo: 14285,
    empId: '33020',
    empJobCategory: 'Validator',
  },
  {
    empNo: 14476,
    empId: '33185',
    empJobCategory: 'Designer',
  }];
```

and want to build array from above information

```
var employeejob=[{'Designer':[12302,13710,13783,15069,14476]},
                    {'Associate Manager':[14785]},
                    {'Validator':'[14285]}
                    ];
```

I did not find any proper mechanism to build this array in JavaScript and from this array want to build following array for high-chart series

```
    var finalchart={series:[7,5,1,1], 
category:['Total','Designer','Associate Manager','Validator']};
```

Comment: Seems like some backend guy don't want to send the exact data.

Comment: i provided exact data

Comment: @anagha affinity you can build object of employeejob and than loop through your main loop and add specefic property you need in employeejob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Your new object
var obj = {};
// loop through the objects in array
employeeinfo.map(function(e){
   // check if the object is already created or not
   if(!obj[e.empJobCategory]){
       // if not created then initialize it as an array
       obj[e.empJobCategory] = [];
   }
   // push the new empNo in the created/present array
   obj[e.empJobCategory].push(e.empNo);
});

// see the output
console.dir(obj);
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8j40L9rp/)**

Can also be done using `Array.reduce()`.

```
var obj = employeeinfo.reduce(function(p, c, i, a) {
  if (!p[c.empJobCategory]) {
    p[c.empJobCategory] = [];
  }
  p[c.empJobCategory].push(c.empNo);
  return p;
}, {});

console.dir(obj);
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8j40L9rp/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try another way

```
function groupBy( array , f )
{
  var groups = {};
  array.forEach( function( o )
  {
    var group = JSON.stringify( f(o) );
    groups[group] = groups[group] || [];
    groups[group].push( o.empNo );  
  });
  return Object.keys(groups).map( function( group )
  {
    return groups[group]; 
  })
}
```

Then

```
var result = groupBy(employeeinfo, function(item)
{
  return [item.empJobCategory];
});
```

The print

```
console.dir(result)
```